# How do I debug critical JavaScript errors (syntax/SCRIPT1002) in Visual Studio or IE11?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, internet-explorer-11

I have a web app that crashes in IE11 with an uninformative “SCRIPT1002”. It’s not a Javascript runtime error; so the F12 dev tools are no help: I cannot break on the error (since it’s not a Javascript exception), and the only information about the error location points to a `blob:` URL, not a `.js` file.

> SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
>   blob:60AFFCE5-6A4E-418D-B628-9DFA4578396A

Needless to say, the `blob:` URL does not actually open to any code.

Trying to attach Visual Studio to IE, I still can’t seem to find out what the actual error is. Visual Studio pops up an error dialogue with:

> JavaScript critical error at line 1, column 663 in blob:60AFFCE5-6A4E-418D-B628-9DFA4578396A\n\nSCRIPT1002: Syntax error

With a `blob:` URL, I don’t see how I can look up the error location; with no details beyond `Syntax error`, I cannot infer it.

Is there any way using IE11 and/or Visual Studio (Community) to find out what the problematic code is, and/or the details of the syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Developer Tools Tool IE11:

- In IE11, press the <kbd>F12</kbd> key. That will open the Developer Tools
- Reload your page or do whatever will trigger the error and you will see it in the **Console** tab
- Double-click on the error and it will take you to the error location in the code in the **Debug** tab.

You have several debug tools in the **Debug** tab such as **Watches**, **Call Stack**, and **Breakpoints**. You can also execute your JavaScript code line by line.

Comment: Sadly, no. It just tells me the same thing—`SCRIPT1002` `Syntax error` in `blob:[UUID]`. No indication of which JS file, or what the syntax error is. Additionally, it’s not a JS runtime exception, so I cannot break on it in the F12 dev tools.

Comment: Yes, of course it will tell you the same thing, but did you try to double-click on it to go to the error location in the code?

Comment: Yes. It shows `Loading blob:[UUID]...` and then does nothing (never loads).

Comment: Close the Developer Tools and reopen, then try again.

Comment: Trust me, I’ve tried that twice, and thrice, and twenty times, and on three or four different machines.

Comment: Is that JavaScript code from some library? Usually libraries come in two flavours, development and production. The production version is usually minified, but it can also be obfuscated. If that's the case for you, you may need to look for the development version and use it for debugging.

Comment: Since I don’t know the code location—note, from the question, that it’s pointing to a mysterious UUID-labelled `blob:` URL and not to any Javascript file—I have no way of knowing whether the problem arises in library or application code. That’s precisely why I asked the question in the first place. (Toggling obfuscation makes no difference, FWIW.)

Comment: Yes, I understand that you don't know the exact location, but you must know if it is from your code or not, unless you didn't write that code. Also you should know what libraries are referenced in your website, it's not that hard. All JavaScript references are easy to find in the HTML code (usually in the `<head>` or at the end of the `<body>`). If the project is written in a server-side framework like ASP.Net, then the framework adds its own JavaScript files too, but it's easy to distinguish between them. Anyway, run your website in Chrome and press F12 to see if its debugger will work better

Comment: The code is transpiled JS of many hundreds of kB, involving hundreds of npm dependencies. In Chrome, the problem does not occur. I’m asking about IE11 specifically because it is an IE11-specific problem.

Comment: I see. When you attach VS to IE11, does it not take you to the location? Does it also do something silly like the IE11 Developer Tools? Perhaps you can load the source code in VS and see if it gives you better info. That will only work if the source code is either written in pure HTML/JS or ASP.Net.